# Cycle through jComboBox

Tags: java, swing

I have a bunch of jComboBox in a panel.  What is the best way to cycle through the panel and set setSelectedIndex(0) for each of the controls?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? or any piece of code available?

Comment: what do you mean cycle through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list to keep track of all the combo boxes being added to the panel, and then loop over them. For example:

```
List<JComboBox> list = new ArrayList<JComboBox>();

JComboBox box = new JComboBox();
panel.add(box);
list.add(box); //store reference to the combobox in list

// Later, loop over the list
for(JComboBox b: list){
    b.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over a tree of `Component`s by checking whether each `Component` is an instance of `Container`, and if so iterate over the container's child components and so forth.  You could wrap this functionality in a `ComponentIterator`, which is initialised with the root Component in the hierarchy.  This would allow you to iterate over a component tree and initialise each `JComboBox` to a specific value.

**However**, I would not recommend this "generic" approach as it could have unforeseen results as your code evolves over time.  Instead, it would probably make sense to write a simply factory method that creates and initialises your `JComboBox`; e.g.

```
private JComboBox createCombo(Object[] items) {
  JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(items);

  if (items.length > 0) {
    cb.setSelectedIndex(0);
  }

  return cb;
}
```

Here's the `ComponentIterator` implementation in case it's of any use:

```
public class ComponentIterator implements Iterator<Component> {
    private final Stack<Component> components = new Stack<Component>();

    /**
     * Creates a <tt>ComponentIterator</tt> with the specified root {@link java.awt.Component}.
     * Note that unless this component is a {@link java.awt.Container} the iterator will only ever return one value;
     * i.e. because the root component does not contain any child components.
     *
     * @param rootComponent Root component
     */
    public ComponentIterator(Component rootComponent) {
        components.push(rootComponent);
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return !components.isEmpty();
    }

    public Component next() {
        if (components.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        Component ret = components.pop();

        if (ret instanceof Container) {
            for (Component childComponent : ((Container) ret).getComponents()) {
                components.push(childComponent);
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```